# Inverse polynomial map $\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}^2$ growing faster than $2^{2^n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Let $P, Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x, y]$ be polynomials with zero constant terms. Assume the induced map $\phi_{P, Q}:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}^2$ is injective. An example is $P=x+x^3 y^2, Q=y+x^2 y^3$.

Can the map $f_{P, Q}:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $$f_{P, Q}(n)=\sup_{|\phi_{P, Q}(v)|\leq n}|v|$$
grow faster than $2^{2^n}$?

The norm above is the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Why do you think such a thing exists?

Comment: I believe that this is a good question, but, to possibly clarify Emil's comment, you should rather ask it as *"Does there exist..."* (you can do so by editing the question).

Comment: Do you know about weaker versions of this question, for instance requiring that it grows faster than any polynomial? How about faster than exponential?

Comment: Let's start by ignoring the growth condition altogether and asking whether there are polynomials defining a bijection at all. Well, there are linear ones, but what else?

Comment: Note that the question has been edited into something very different since the earlier comments were posted.

Comment: It might be simpler to avoid the norming, and define $f_{P,Q}(n)=\sup(\{x+y:|P(x,y)|+|Q(x,y)|\le n\})$ instead.

Comment: Apart from minor points, the main differences with the original phrasing is that $\phi$ is now assumed to be injective rather than bijective, and that $\phi$ was assumed to be $\mathbf{Z}^n\to\mathbf{Z}^n$, and now $n=2$ is assumed.